# DNS resolution error on only one device in LAN

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, dns, pihole

I've encountered very intriguing behavior in my home LAN.

One of my devices (main computer) refuses to work with my Pi-Hole (resolution error - it's like there was no DNS server configured at all). All other devices work properly (computers, smartphones, you name it).

My setup is as follows:

Main router (which is a gateway) is acting also as DHCP server and points to my home DNS.
My Banana-Pi runs  Armbian buster with Linux 5.4.28-sunxi with Pi-Hole (also acts as a samba server).

So - when a device is connected it get and address 192.168.5.104/24, gateway 192.168.5.1 and DNS 192.168.5.2.

All devices work no problem with this setup but one. It get configured (it runs freshly installed Windows 10) with proper DNS and gateway but it refuses to resolve any addresses...

Previously I was running Windows 8.1 on it nad the problem also occured but only after a minute or two after reboot. And if you were patient enough it starter working for an hour or so and then stopped...

I suspected OS and reinstalled it. Now - sometimes it works but more often it doesn't.

I've looked at the pihole.log file but nothing came up... And right now when I'm actually to troubleshoot this it just works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Culprit here was either PiHole or device running it**. First I was running it on RaspberryPie, then tried BananaPie with the lates PiHole version.

Ultimately I decided to switch to old netbook (1GB RAM, 1GHz cpu).

Since then I have no problems with DNS resolving. But I noticed that I'm running (again) even later version so bad for troubleshooting.

**My gueasses are that either it was platform issue (arm vs i386) or just at some version PiHole started working properly.**